# Foreach a model in codeigniter existing array

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, foreach, model

On my controller, i want to foreach another models to add the result in the existing array.

My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $getConcerts_previous = $this->concert_model->getAllConcerts('previous');

    foreach($getConcerts_previous as $concert) {
        $hallData = $this->hall_model->getHallbyID($concert->cHall_ID);
        $concert->hHall_ID = isset($hallData) ? $hallData->hID : 'No data';
    }

    $this->render_layout('concerts/index', $this->data);
}
```

**Actualy when i @varp_dump my '$getConcerts_previous' on my view, I have:**

```
  public 'cID' => string '45' (length=2)
  public 'cBand_ID' => string '8' (length=1)
  public 'cDate' => string '2018-06-22' (length=10)
```

**And i want to know how add on this var dump for example**

```
  public 'cID' => string '45' (length=2)
  public 'cBand_ID' => string '8' (length=1)
  public 'cDate' => string '2018-06-22' (length=10)
  public 'hHall_ID' => string '1' (length=1)
```

My database:

```
Concerts: cID | cName | cPlaceType | cPlaceID
Festivals: fID | fName
Halls: hID | hName
```

If cPlaceType = 1, select festival with cPlaceID, If cPlaceType = 2, select hall with cPlaceID,

Comment: What you want is not clear. Is it that you want to add `hHall_ID` to the first var_dump?

Comment: @DFriend Yes :) On my foreach, i have all infos about concert (prefix c), now i juste want all infos about hall

Comment: Do you want to add `$hallData` into `$getConcerts_previous` ?

Comment: Post code for `concert_model->getAllConcerts(){..}`

Comment: @RyukLee Yes, if "$concert->cHall_ID" is 1, he select the Hall infos with id 1 and add to the array $getConcerts_previous

Comment: @KarloKokkak Hi. You need this part of code ? i know i can make join, but before i need to test if its festival or hall, if festival "selectfestivalbyID", if hall "selecthallbyID" :/

Comment: does `$getConcerts_previous` has `cHall_ID`? I don't see in the `varp_dump my '$getConcerts_previous' `

Comment: show us your tables structor

Comment: @RyukLee Thanks for your reply. I updated my post

Comment: check my answer. By the way, your if else is the same action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public function index()
{
$this->data['getConcerts_next'] = $this->concert_model->getAllConcerts('next');

$getConcerts_previous = $this->concert_model->getAllConcerts('previous');

foreach($getConcerts_previous as $concert) {
  if($concert->cPlaceType == 1) {
    $hallData = $this->hall_model->getHallbyID($concert->cPlaceID);        
     //$concert->hHall_ID = isset($hallData) ? $hallData->hID : 'No data';  
     $concert->hallData = $hallData;  
     $concert->festivalData = NULL;
  } else {
    $festivalData = $this->festival_model->getFestivalbyID($concert->cPlaceID);     
     //$concert->hHall_ID =  isset($festivalData) ? $festivalData->fID : 'No data';           
     $concert->hallData = NULL;  
     $concert->festivalData = $festivalData;
  } 
}
var_dump($getConcerts_previous);
//include below line and you can pass data to view;
 $this->data['getConcerts_previous'] = $getConcerts_previous;
 $this->render_layout('concerts/index', $this->data);
}
```

In model

```
public function getHallById($hallID) { 
  $this->db->where('hID', $hallID); 
  return $this->db->get($this->table)->row(); 
}

public function getFestivalById($hallID) { 
  $this->db->where('fID', $festivalID); 
  return $this->db->get($this->table)->row(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply (i edit my if else ^^) 
I have this error actually: Message: Trying to get property of non-object Line Number: 18 (This line: $concert->hHall_ID = $hallData->hID;)

My query is:
    public function getHallById($hallID)
    {
        $this->db->where('hID', $hallID);
        $this->db->get($this->table);
        return $this->db->get()->row();
    }

Comment: show me `$this->festival_model->getFestivalbyID($concert->cPlaceID)` function

Comment: public function getFestivalById($hallID)
    {
        $this->db->where('fID', $festivalID);
        $this->db->get($this->table);
        return $this->db->get()->row();
    }

Comment: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1096

Aucune table utilisée

SELECT *

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/concerts/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: I don't understand your query? Why did you say `If cPlaceType = 1, select festival with cPlaceID, If cPlaceType = 2, select hall with cPlaceID`. But in function `getFestivalById` you put condition `fID` and in function `getHallById` you put condition `hID`. In if else you put cPlaceID to run 2 queries ?

Comment: My problem actually is not the if cPlaceType, i already use this function. I juste to know how take the data from festival or hall, and add it to my actual array "$getConcerts_previous" . after is just a IF, and call different model with the same query, juste the table change

Comment: fix this `$this->db->where('hID', $hallID); $this->db->get($this->table)->row();`

Comment: I try it. Thanks, i dont have any error. Juste, to call my foreach in the view, i use witch var ? Thanks

I put this to try for the moment:
        foreach($getConcerts_previous as $concert) {
            $hallData = $this->hall_model->getHallbyID($concert->cHall_ID);
            $concert->hHall_ID = isset($hallData) ? $hallData->hID : 'No data';
        }
        
        $this->render_layout('concerts/index', $this->data);

Comment: `Juste, to call my foreach in the view, i use witch var ?` I don't understand your question

Comment: On my view, i make "<?php @var_dump($getConcerts_previous);die;?>" and he return me "null" :(

Comment: update your full controller code in your question please

Comment: You don't pass the data from `controller` to `view` yet

Comment: Your the man of the situation :D ! Juste last question... how take all data from the row of Hall ? I juste have id for the moment

Comment: The same with `hHall_ID`, check my last edited. By the way, accept the answer if my answer is right

Comment: Thanks you guy... really !